# Kafka Consumer frontend in javascript html

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, video-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

The kafka producer is sending the frames and I want to consume that frames and whenever that frames is consumed I want to display that frame on html. I've seen I've to use nodejs for consumer to consume the data but how can I evoke or updates the data to the clients or on the frontend side whenever I recieve the data. Do we need to use some sort of websocket or something? Please help me with frontend side of kafka consumer in js.

Comment: You could use the Kafka REST Proxy or a websocket. You shouldn't expose the bootstrap-servers over the open internet for a direct frontend connection (even if that did work, it'd likely have high latency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used websocket to communicate between consumer and the html as soon as consumer consumes data, html who is subscribe to that topic will take data using websocket